# Split list in tuple with lists of length 2^0, 2^1, ... , 2^N using Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, split

I'm trying to solve Haskell problem, but I don't have any clue where to start.
I need to split list in lists with length of 2^0, 2^1, 2^3 .. elements. 
So if we have list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]` after using our function we should have result `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13]]`

Comment: I do not really get why you first split on `even` and `odd`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, it's probably non important information, it was the problem that I solved eralier but now I need to solve probelm that I stated in question. I removed non important information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function: [`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a],[a])`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:splitAt), and then use recursion:

```
blocks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
blocks _ [] = []
blocks n ls = la : blocks (2*n) lb
    where ~(la,lb) = splitAt n ls
```

So in the case we have a `blocks 1 [1,2,3,4,5,6]` we will obtain `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]`. In the first case, we look if the list we give to blocks is empty, in which case, there is nothing to split, so we return the empty list. In the recursive case, we `splitAt` the `ls` list into `la` and `lb`. The `la` is our first list, and the `lb` we need to split further. We do the recursion with `n*2` as new split length to ensure that the length of the lists will increase like powers of two.

Comment: cool solution, I was writting the same just with `take` and `drop` wich is basically worst than yours

Comment: @DanielSanchez: well of course it depends on how `splitAt` is implemented, but usually they aim to save some work like [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#splitAt).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can also use `zip` and `groupBy`. Seems to be working, but is not so straightforward.

```
import Data.List
a="Hello World!"
p=[2^n| n<-[0..]]
pa=take (length a) p
b=[elem n pa| n<-[1..length a]]
c=zip a b
d=groupBy (\x y->snd y==False) c
e=map (map (\x->fst x)) d
```